How to run Tauri without dev server?
I'm using Tauri 2.0 RC. The basic problem I have is that I want to disable auto reload because every time I save the Rust code, or do anything else such as run unit tests, the app restarts and brings the main window to the foreground. Auto reloading for the front end is fine, as it only refreshes the web view.
I can do this:
pnpm tauri dev --no-watch

Then, I can restart the whole thing when I want to rebuild the Rust code. This works fine, but it has a slight performance issue that every time the dev server for the FE is also restarted. The help says that the --no-dev-server is exactly for this. I should be able to manually start the dev server then do this:
pnpm tauri dev --no-watch --no-dev-server

Except that it doesn't work. It still tries to start the dev server. Is this a bug or am I doing somehting wrong?

You can first start the frontend with pnpm dev, which utilizes Vite's hot reload feature to automatically update the front end. Then, use cargo run to start the backend, so that the front end won't reload every time you start the application.
